# Can I install a trial version of Visual Studio 2010 Professional after Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate expires?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Will I be abe to to install a trial version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional after the current  trial Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate expires? Yes both are trial versions. I have already extended the Ultimate i'm currently using to 90 days and it expires in a few days time.

Please don't ask me to consider buying because i'm working in a company where request to purchase Visual Studio license takes forever. My project is very short-termed that's why I opted to use the trial versions.

Information appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can install free Express edition.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. The express edition lacks certain functionalities that I may need. That's why I'm asking if I could install Professional trial first before resorting to express

Comment: You could try. Seems like you have no other options :-)

Comment: does this mean that installing the Professional trial would not work because i've been using Ultimate trial already?

Comment: Define "would work". I think that your trial won't be prolonged.

Comment: would work = running fine, able to connect to sql server database,  able to program and create applications and can be used for 30 days (like a new trial). When you mentioned "won't be prolonged" the newly installed Professional trial will have the 30 days or it will just continue off from the leftover days from the current Ultimate? Thanks for your help

Comment: What's the point in speculating? Uninstall Ultimate and install Professional. It won't make things worse.

Comment: true enough. just afraid something might go wrong during installation. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility"?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw(VS.100).aspx#uninstalling

Comment: actually has good info. thanks